# Using DRF pagination with ListSerializer cause exception

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

The problem is when I'm using `ListSerializer` with `pagination` on `DRF` I get exception.

I have the following codes

> serializers.py

```
class IsDeletedFilteredListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        data = data.filter(is_deleted=False)
        return super(IsDeletedFilteredListSerializer, self).to_representation(data)


class GallerySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        list_serializer_class = IsDeletedFilteredListSerializer  


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    galleries = GallerySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        list_serializer_class = IsDeletedFilteredListSerializer
```

> views.py

```
class ProductView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    model = Product
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'head','patch']

    paginate_by = 20


class GalleryView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = GallerySerializer
    model = Gallery
    filter_fields = ('product',)
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'head','patch']
```

When I try to get products:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'

but when I remove `paginate_by = 20` everything works ok.
That seems pagination occurs before ListFilter and converts queryset to list.

Because I use `Django Admin interface`, it's not proper to change ObjectManager and because I use `nested serializers` overriding queryset on views does not work either (filters products and nested galleries will not filter).

> I'm using Django 1.8.6 with DRF  3.1.3 on Python 3.4

Comment: why don't you override the `get_queryset` method in your ModelViewSet and do the filter there?

Comment: It does not affect nested serializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by filtering your `Products` in `get_queryset` and use `IsDeletedFilteredListSerializer` to only filter your `galleries`.

You can do like:

```
class ProductView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'head','patch']
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(is_deleted=False)
```

and in your `ProductSerializer` remove the `list_serializer_class` option in serializer Meta class.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    galleries = GallerySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

This way you can filter both `products` and `gallaries`